Download dataset in specific directory
I am trying to download from kaggle in the DL directory by using this :
!kaggle datasets download -d scribbless/another-anime-face-dataset -p "/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/SR/DL/"

When I open the DL after the download completed I found the DL is empty. Why? what is the wrong?
